# Any dynamic organisation chart avaiable in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex3, flex-charts

Does anyone know of any opensource tool for creating dynamic organization chart in flex by reading values from database

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at KapLab (http://lab.kapit.fr)

They have free data vizualisation components. I think you might be interested by the Visualizer component.

It's not open-source though, but you can get the source code if you buy a licence.

(If you need more info, you can still contact me because I'm working closely with them)

Comment: +1 : i'm looking into these myself, impressive set of components.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM ILog Elixer](http://www.ilog.com/visualization/trials/) library has an [organization charting component](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=14500;illustIndex=0;docIndex=0).  It's not free, but it fits the bill of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The most polished "free" components I've seen are the [KapLab Visualizer](http://lab.kapit.fr/display/visualizer/Visualizer) that Pez mentioned.

However for actual open source your best be is the [BirdEye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/) Information Visualization and Visual Analytics Library.  Check out the [demo](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html), the "Graphs" tab and I think tree is right up your alley.  BirdEye is built with [degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) as is [axiis](http://axiis.org/) another open source data visualization library.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe The Flare library would suit your needs , I am starting to use it. Looks kinda funky

http://flare.prefuse.org/